# Lenovo Ideapad 320 - Touchpad doesn't work

Tags: drivers, touchpad, lenovo, elantech

My touchpad is working with Windows, but not with Ubuntu. I believe I require drivers for Ubuntu. On the Lenovo site I can't find a driver for Ubuntu or for any Linux distro. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

The fix was uploaded yesterday look at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1708852

so just do update via `apt` and your touchpad will working like a charm :D

tested in Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS my leptop Lenovo Ideapad 320-15IKB

Comment: it worked after i update kernel from 4.8 to 4.10  sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04

Comment: I actually had 4.10 installed when I downloaded Ubuntu for my ideapad 320 and it wasn't working. Had to upgrade to 4.13.16 and works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

I was disappointed. Then I discovered a solution.

1. Upgrade your kernel to 4.13.* version. (Touchpad will work.)
2. If you are facing problem on wifi driver then, find out your wifi by `lspci | grep Wirless`. And then, install any driver that supports that model. A lots of open source drivers are available for linux.

Comment: How did you upgrade your kernal?

Comment: I have `ukuu` for my Linux mint. But also workable for ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Hay guys! today I have installed "Ubuntu 18.04 LTS" on my Lenovo 320 and mouse pad, wifi, sound, display brightness key everything works just perfect. So the issue is solved now. Thanks to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS