# Elantech touchpad not working in Ubuntu 16.04.3 on Lenovo Ideapad 320

Tags: drivers, touchpad, lenovo, elantech

I recently bought a Lenovo Ideapad 320 and installed Ubuntu 16.04.3 on it. Installation went well, but while typing my password I realised that my touchpad wasn't working. How can I find out what the problem is and solve it?

Comment: [You're not alone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946015/lenevo-ideapad-320-touchpad-doesnt-work) but no answer yet.

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly your problem and case
I have linux ubuntu **16.04.3**  and **lenovo ideapad 320**

1) update your linux from software updater , i did all updates.
2) update security , and any other updates via command line
3) upgrade your kernel to latest, in my case i upgraded from 4.8 to 4.10.0

**P.S**
I have 64 bit system. 
If i were you i can test with live cd ubuntu to proof its working. and it did work

**References**
About upgrading i used something like this

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

and you can check your version by

```
uname --kernel-version
```